# Problema de sintaxis con función Javascript

Tags: javascript, funcion

Estoy desarrollando una tarea que me dieron en mi bootcamp, tengo la siguiente duda:

```
function obtenerAreaRectangulo(alto, ancho) {
  // Retornar el area de un rectángulo teniendo su altura y ancho
  // Tu código:

}
```

Se que si es un rectángulo, básicamente debería multiplicar `* 2` el `alto` como el `ancho`, pero ¿cómo debería ser la sintaxis en este caso? no logro que me de el OK.

He intentado:

```
return (alto + ancho *2);
return alto + ancho *2;
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Sabes la fórmula del [área de un rectángulo](https://www.google.com/search?q=area+rectangulo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esasa matemáticas :). El área de un rectángulo es basexaltura Pero bueno la pregunta es el return de la función. Da igual

```
return (alto*ancho)    
return alto*ancho
```

Así en resumen: en ambos casos primero se evalúa la expresión antes de hacer el return.

Comment: Gracias Juan! era eso: